# Rename woocommerce button

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, buttons

I would like to rename a WooCommerce shop page button from SELECT OPTIONS to SELECT VALUE.
Can someone provide instructions? I am not a professional programmer.
Thanks,
Melissa

Comment: Hello @MelissaGallagher - Welcome to the WordPress Development community! Unfortunately, our expertise is in custom extension of WordPress itself - questions regarding 3rd-party products require extremely intimate knowledge of extremely specialized code in order to answer well, and thus are considered off-topic. The official support channels for the product in question are more capable of providing the most appropriate and robust solutions.

Answer (score 1):

This should be off topic since it's about WooCommerce, but it just happens that I already had done this so here it goes

One thing to consider is that each product type has it's button. So in your case, `SELECT OPTIONS` refers to a `variable` product type

of course, you don't need to switch through every possible scenario, but since my code had it, I'm keeping it so you see other possible use of this function

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'wpse_woo_custom_cart_button_text' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'wpse_woo_custom_cart_button_text' );
function wpse_woo_custom_cart_button_text() {

  global $product;

  $product_type = $product->get_type();

  // To modify on a single product page
  if( $product_type == 'variable-subscription' || $product_type == 'variable' ){
    if( is_single() )
        return __( 'Buy Now', 'my-textdomain' );
    else
        return __( 'Choose options', 'my-textdomain' );
  }
  // To modify on the shop page
  else{
    switch ( $product_type ) {
      case 'external':
        return __( 'Buy Now', 'my-textdomain' );
      break;
      case 'grouped':
        return __( 'View products', 'my-textdomain' );
      break;
      case 'simple':
        return __( 'Buy Now', 'my-textdomain' );
      break;
  // here's your use case
      case 'variable':
        return __( 'Select Value', 'my-textdomain' );
       break;
  // Not a default product type
      case 'booking':
        return __( 'Book Now', 'my-textdomain' );
      break;
      default:
        return __( 'Learn more', 'my-textdomain' );
    }
  }
}
```

you can put this into your `functions.php` file